# Installing WEC 2013

Tags: windows-embedded-compact, windows-embedded, windows-embedded-8, windows-embedded-8.1

I'm experiencing so many different problems installing WEC 2013 - it fails at various points, depending of what I select. I tried downloading all the different update versions ISOs from MSDN and they all fail in one way or the other. One of the many failure examples is this dialog:

[image: Shared source dialog]

I purposefully did NOT select Shared Source check button on the previous screen, yet the installer wants to install it. It's nowhere to be found on the DVD. It says to click the download button but download button is disabled. If I click OK, it just re-pops up the same window. If I click cancel, it aborts the installation.

Installation log is not particularly helpful, either:

```
[0E7C:0CCC][2015-03-07T11:18:46.474-06:00]: The installer asked to resolve source for package 'SharedSource' and payload '1'.
[0E7C:0E84][2015-03-07T11:18:46.474-06:00]: Setting string variable 'DownloadAll' to value '1'
[0E7C:0E84][2015-03-07T11:18:47.319-06:00]: Setting string variable 'DownloadAll' to value '0'
[0E7C:0CCC][2015-03-07T11:18:48.417-06:00]: Setting string variable 'DownloadCurrent' to value '0'
[0E7C:0CCC][2015-03-07T11:18:48.417-06:00]: Setting string variable 'DownloadAll' to value '0'
[0E7C:0CCC][2015-03-07T11:18:48.417-06:00]: Caching of package 'SharedSource' completed. HRESULT 0x80070642.
[0E7C:0CCC][2015-03-07T11:18:48.417-06:00]: The user canceled the installation when caching package 'SharedSource' completed.
[0E7C:0CCC][2015-03-07T11:18:48.417-06:00]: The installer finished the caching phase. HRESULT 0x80070642
[0E7C:0CCC][2015-03-07T11:18:48.419-06:00]: Setting string variable 'DownloadPhaseActive' to value '0'
[0E7C:0CCC][2015-03-07T11:18:48.419-06:00]: Rolling back the cached content as there was an error while caching. HRESULT 0x80070642
```

Operating system is Windows 8.1 Enterprise with Visual Studio 2013 Professional, Update 4 installed. If anyone could shed some light on a "recipe" for successful WEC installation, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it installed. The ISO was: en_windows_embedded_compact_2013_update_5_x86_and_x64_dvd_4083417.iso

It would not install without Platform Builder (which I don't need) - it is not enabled on setup unless Application Builder (separate download) is previously installed. Without Application Builder, Platform Builder and a couple of other components have red "X" icon next to them but setup allows to continue only to fail after it runs for a while.